# How to get values from JSON response

Tags: c#, json, json-deserialization

I have to JSON response comes from database API.

My JSON data:

```
{
    "AccessToken":"1929c63a-9c72-4c0d-aea8-345c0b5411e9",
    "LoggedInUserID":1,
    "LookupData":{
        "LiquiditySources":[
            {
                "ID":1,
                "ParentID":null,
                "Name":"testname1",
                "SequenceNo":null,
                "Caption":"test1",
                "ConnectivityInfo":
                    "{\"Port\":11111,\"Username\":testuser1,\"Password\":\"password1\"}"
            },
            {
                "ID":2,
                "ParentID":null,
                "Name":"testname2",
                "SequenceNo":null,
                "Caption":"test2",
                "ConnectivityInfo":
                    "{\"Port\":22222,\"Username\":testuser2,\"Password\":\"password2\"}"
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

I want to store this response values in different variables please anyone help me this is my final year project. I am using windows application c#

Comment: Maybe this can help you - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6620165/how-can-i-parse-json-with-c

Comment: Invalid json, please at least provide correct json

Comment: this is parsed json data

Comment: JSON is valid if he remove the `,` before the last `}`

Comment: [json2csharp.com](http://json2csharp.com/)

Comment: http://www.newtonsoft.com/json

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should deserialize this JSON to class and then do whatever you want with the class object.

You can use NewtonSoft.Json dll for this purpose.

```
public class LiquiditySource
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public object ParentID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public object SequenceNo { get; set; }
    public string Caption { get; set; }
    public string ConnectivityInfo { get; set; }
}

public class LookupData
{
    public List<LiquiditySource> LiquiditySources { get; set; }
}

public class SampleClass
{
    public string AccessToken { get; set; }
    public int LoggedInUserID { get; set; }
    public LookupData LookupData { get; set; }
}

string json = "your json string";
SampleClass obj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<SampleClass>(json);
```

You can get properties like this:

```
List<LiquiditySource> ls =  obj.LookupData.LiquiditySources;
    foreach(LiquiditySource liquiditySource in ls)
    {
        string connectivityInfo = liquiditySource.ConnectivityInfo;

    }
```

If you want only to get all `ConnectivityInfo` values, you can also use `LINQ`.

```
List<string> lsConnectivityInfo = obj.LookupData.LiquiditySources.Select(c => c.ConnectivityInfo).ToList();
```

If you want to furthur deserilize `connectivityInfo` string to object and get its property, then you have to again deserialize it to object. 
Note: You have to modify your JSON too.

Modified JSON:

```
{
    "AccessToken": "1929c63a-9c72-4c0d-aea8-345c0b5411e9",
    "LoggedInUserID": 1,
    "LookupData": {
        "LiquiditySources": [{
            "ID": 1,
            "ParentID": null,
            "Name": "testname1",
            "SequenceNo": null,
            "Caption": "test1",
            "ConnectivityInfo": "{\"Port\":11111,\"Username\":\"testuser1\",\"Password\":\"password1\"}"
        }, {
            "ID": 2,
            "ParentID": null,
            "Name": "testname2",
            "SequenceNo": null,
            "Caption": "test2",
            "ConnectivityInfo": "{\"Port\":22222,\"Username\":\"testuser2\",\"Password\":\"password2\"}"
        }]
    }
}
```

Make one more class:

```
public class ConnectivityInfo
{
    public int Port { get; set; }
    public string Username { get; set; }
    public string Password { get; set; }
}
```

Then do this:

```
foreach (LiquiditySource liquiditySource in ls)
    {
        string connectivityInfo = liquiditySource.ConnectivityInfo;
        ConnectivityInfo connectivityInfoObj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ConnectivityInfo>(connectivityInfo);

    }
```

Comment: You forgot to mention [json2csharp.com](http://json2csharp.com/) generated the classes 

Comment: There are other utilities also which can do this, and it was not part of code thats y I have not mentioned ;)

Comment: I got other values but how I can get ConnectivityInfo values?

Comment: I sucked  because I need Port, UserName, and Password values but it returned me string values I don't know how can I get these values.

Comment: U need properties or their values?

Comment: Yes! I need values. e.g for first iteration Port=11111, Username=testuser1,Password=password1

Comment: Very thanks @vivek nuna I have solved this by JObject ConnectivityInfo = JObject.Parse(liquiditySource.ConnectivityInfo); thank you for help

Comment: I am sorry Vivek! I don't have 15 reputation I am unavailable to vote you